# HTML iframe with different domain src: how to disable the click but keep the hover intact

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have this iframe whose source is some other domain. Since the iframe contains some links that i don't want to work. I am trying to disable the click but need the hover to work over iframe.

```
<iframe id='myframe' style='width: 1000px; height: 700px;' src='http://www.voyant-tools.org/tool/Cirrus/?visible=335&corpus=9ecfdf31007fbd721c5b414ea9294b5c'></iframe>
```

I have tried using css:

```
#myframe{
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

But this also disables the hover. How can i disable the click but keep the hover intact ?

Comment: You can't prevent some events and not others in cross domain iframe. It's all or none

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve the desired by adding a transparent layer upon your existing iframe.
You have to declare another `<div>` inside the iframe and then add the following style property to it

```
.overlay {
background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.0);
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

Comment: i have tried that, it stops both hover and click. I just want the click to stop, not the hover.